# Understanding Scanf in Go

Tags: go, scanf

I am not sure how to use `Scanf` function. Let's say I want to input number 10 on scan. By doing that, shouldn't the output be 0xA?

Also, how do I use the function with two or more scan arguments (e.g. `fmt.Scanf("%x", &e, &f, &g)`)?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var e int

    fmt.Scanf("%#X", &e)
    fmt.Println(e)

}
```

Answer (score 17):

You have to first take your input as an int and then print the hex value :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    var e int

    fmt.Scanf("%d", &e)
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%#X\n", e)

}
```

Output is :

```
go run main.go 
10
0XA
```

For multiple inputs :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    var e int
    var s string

    fmt.Scanf("%d %s", &e, &s)
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%#X \t%s\n", e, s)

}
```

Output is :

```
go run main.go
10 hello
0XA     hello
```

**Update : fmt.Scanf() vs fmt.Scan()**

Scan is able to loop :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    var e int
    var f int
    var g int

    fmt.Scan(&e, &f, &g)
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%d - %d - %d", e, f, g)
}
```

Output is :

```
go run main.go
10
11
12
10 - 11 - 12
```

Scanf is able to """filter""" from a formated string :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    var e int
    var f int

    fmt.Scanf("%d Scanf %d", &e, &f)
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%d - %d", e, f)
}
```

Output is :

```
go run main.go 
10 Scanf 11
10 - 11
```

Comment: What is the difference between `Scanf` and `Scan`? This may sound trivial, but I'm kinda confused. What if format in `Scanf` is `%d smth %s`? It seems like "`smth`" doesn't have any purpose.